# My program doesn't find EOF symbol

Tags: c, eof

I have this program which deletes from an .txt file all the words, which start and end with the same symbol. In my opinion it should work, but somehow it doesn't stop when EOF is reached and ir prints me some strange chinese symbols...

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 255

void search(char *symbolMass, FILE *duomFail, FILE *rezFail)
{
    int i = 0, k =0, j =0, p = 0;
    char symbol = 0;
    char *rezMass;
    char word[20];

    rezMass = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);

    while(simbolis != EOF)
    {
        printf("veikia");
        symbol = symbolMass[i];

        if (symbol != 32 && symbol != 10 && symbol != EOF)
        {
            word[j] = symbol;
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        else
        {
            word[j] = symbol;
            i++;
            if(word [0] == word[j - 1])
            {
                rezMass[k] = word[j];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
               for (p = 0; p <= j; p++, k++)
               {
                   rezMass[k] = word[p];
               }
            }
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        symbolMass[i] = rezMass[i];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *duom, *rez;
    char *symbols;


    symbols = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        duom = fopen (argv[1],"r");
        rez =fopen (argv[2],"w");
        if (duom != NULL)
        {
            while (symbols != NULL)
            {
                fgets(symbols, MAX, duom);
                search(symbols, duom, rez);
                fputs(symbols, rez);
            }
            fclose(duom);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("There is no file with name \"%s\"\n",argv[1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The command has no arguments.\n");
    }

    fclose(rez);
    free(simboliai);

    return 0;
}
```

It works like this: it scans symbols and puts them into "word" till it reaches "space", "new line" or "EOF", then it checks if the word starts and ends with the same symbol, if yes, it prints only the "space", "new line" or "EOF", if not, then it prints the whole word.
Oh, and the code is wrote in C (usiing CodeBlocks if it matters).

Comment: What is `simbolis`? if you compare `symbol` with `EOF`, `symbol` should be an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: It had to be "symbol" forgot to change. And why it should be int? I'm checking for the ASCII codes.

Comment: **EOF** is a largely fictional thing.

Comment: `EOF` is not an ascii value, it is the integer `-1`, which cannot be hold by a `char`.

Comment: When you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), make sure it actually *builds* (unless you have a question about build errors of course). Don't just write it into the question and hope to get it right, because then you will end up with unrelated problems like all your different spellings of the `symbols` variable. All those unrelated problems distracts from the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there *is* no `EOF` character in the buffer you pass to the `search` function. The buffer, `symbolMass` is a *string* and like all strings in C it's terminated by the special null-character `'\0'` (which incidentally happens to be the same as `0`).

I suggest you change your loop to something like this

```
char symbol;

for (int i = 0; (symbol = symbolMass[i]) != '\0'; ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Also, don't use "magic numbers" for characters, use the actual character literals instead, so instead of

```
if (symbol != 32 && symbol != 10 && symbol != EOF)
```

do

```
if (symbol != ' ' && symbol != '\n')
```

Comment: So instead of "while(symbol != EOF)" I should do "while(symbol != '\0')" ?

Comment: There is also the problem with the loop in `main` that doesn't check the return value from `fgets`...

Comment: Okay, I got it now. I'll go try to fix the problems you both mentioned. Thanks! :)